# Ampscript | If statement to find Data extension"FIRST_NAME" or List "First Name" is empty?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to check the First name attribute is empty or not. The problem is the first name attribute of data extension & List attribute naming style is different. (ie. Data extension "FIRST_NAME" or List "First Name").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
%%[

var @firstName, @firstName1, @firstName2
set @firstName1 = AttributeValue("First_Name") /* Data Extension */
set @firstName2 = AttributeValue("First Name") /* Profile Attribute */

if not empty(@firstName1) then
  set @firstName = @firstName1
elseif not empty(@firstName2) then
  set @firstName = @firstName2
else
  set @firstName = "User"
endif

]%%
Dear %%=v(@firstName)=%%,
```

Comment: Works fine. :) Thank you very much Adam. I really appreciate your quick response.